# Using rbind on two matrices to match rows

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have two data frames, `matrix A` and `matrix B`, structured like

```
matrix A
       [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
 [1,]   121  114   117   200 
 [2,]   312  215    78   211
 [3,]   413  121   719   117
```

```
matrix B
       [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
 [1,]   120  119   112   220 
 [2,]     0    7     1     2
 [3,]   412  111   713   113
```

I want to create a new list of data frames  with each sublist being the matches row values from both matrices. So for example, the first new data frame in the list would be

```
matrix C1
       [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
 [1,]   121  114   117   200 
 [2,]   120  119   112   220
```

Row 1 in C1 is Row 1 from matrix A, Row 2 in this new matrix is Row 1 from matrix B. Matrix C2 would be Row 2 from matrix A and B, etc.

I know I have to use `rbind()` at one point, but I'm getting lost on how to get to my desired output?

Comment: "Row 1 in C1 is Row 1 from matrix A, *Row 2 in this new matrix is Row 1 from matrix B*" - looks like Row 2 in the new matrix is **Row 2** from matrix B in your example.

Comment: @thelatemail Whoops, my bad. I edited the post so it's correct now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `BaseR`,

```
lapply(1:nrow(matrixA), function(x) rbind(matrixA[x,],matrixB[x,]))
```

gives,

```
[[1]]
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 52.81736 68.83760 92.26946
[2,] 49.17765 59.02276 15.89793

[[2]]
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 48.21500 35.82741 11.52465
[2,] 33.05838 23.17105 70.05778

[[3]]
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 52.93969 84.12350 21.44636
[2,] 47.69968 73.66894 27.14668
```

**Fake Data:**

```
    matrixA <- matrix(runif(9,1,100),3)
    matrixB <- matrix(runif(9,1,100),3)
```

Comment: How could I add a third row for each list that takes the maximum of each of the columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in an array and use `aperm`.

Starting data

```r
matrixA <- matrix(runif(9,1,100),3)
matrixB <- matrix(runif(9,1,100),3)
list(matrixA, matrixB)    
#> [[1]]
#>           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#> [1,]  7.726875 88.77164 32.74513
#> [2,] 60.005675 26.94784 68.45881
#> [3,] 43.514952 94.43019 21.05740
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 13.48753 65.43023 47.474468
#> [2,] 48.18658 25.19455 16.581541
#> [3,] 60.94665 58.46271  9.016365
```

Make an array and `aperm`

```
list(matrixA, matrixB) |>
  simplify2array() |>
  aperm()
#> , , 1
#> 
#>           [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#> [1,]  7.726875 88.77164 32.74513
#> [2,] 13.487534 65.43023 47.47447
#> 
#> , , 2
#> 
#>          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
#> [1,] 60.00567 26.94784 68.45881
#> [2,] 48.18658 25.19455 16.58154
#> 
#> , , 3
#> 
#>          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 43.51495 94.43019 21.057402
#> [2,] 60.94665 58.46271  9.016365
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: How could I add a third row for each list that takes the maximum of each of the columns?

Comment: Add this to the end of the `|>` chain after `aperm()`: `|> apply(3, \(x) rbind(x, apply(x, 2, max)), simplify = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using row index:

```
# matrix1
M1 <- matrix(c(3:14), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)

# matrix2
M2 <- matrix(c(13:24), nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)

M3 <- rbind(M1[1,], M2[2,])
M3
```

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    4    5
[2,]   16   17   18
```